# Is there any way to get the acSysCmdInitMeter and shows it on the form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following query running in the background when the user press a button on the form.

```vb
    'Insert new data
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_DIRECTORS " & _
             "SELECT importDirectors.* " & _
             "FROM importDirectors LEFT JOIN TBL_DIRECTORS ON importDirectors.[CompanyRegNumber] = TBL_DIRECTORS.[CompanyRegNumber];"

    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    'Update existent data
    strSQL = "UPDATE TBL_DIRECTORS INNER JOIN importDirectors ON (importDirectors.[OperatorName] = " & _
             "TBL_DIRECTORS.[OperatorName]) AND (importDirectors.CompanyRegNumber = TBL_DIRECTORS.CompanyRegNumber) SET "

    For Each field In fields
        strSQL = strSQL & strFormat("TBL_DIRECTORS.[{0}] = [importDirectors].[{1}], ", field.Name, field.Name)
    Next

    strSQL = Left(strSQL, InStrRev(strSQL, ",") - 1) & ";"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

When the UPDATE query is running I know that we have this on the status bar:

[image]

It is a `acSysCmdInitMeter`.

Is there a way to get this and shows in other place, like on my form?

Comment: it could be helpful if we know the name of the object returned by `expression.SysCmd (acSysCmdInitMeter, Argument2, Argument3)`

Comment: Argument2 is the text to display and Argument3 is the maximum value. However, a query within Access is a single atomic process does not allow any way of getting the sort of feedback you are after.